# angular array isn't passing to main controller form object

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have an EventController and use EventService for saving to localStorage.

```
vm.event = event;
    function event() {
        vm.dataLoading = true;
        EventService.Create(vm.events)  //save using ( api/events/ + id )
            .then(function (response) {
                if (response.success) {
                    FlashService.Success('Event created successful', true);
                    $location.path('/events');
                } else {
                    FlashService.Error(response.message);
                    vm.dataLoading = false;
                }
            });
    }
```

View All Events:

```
  <td>{{events.eventType}} </td>
  <td>{{events.eventName}}</td>
  ...
```

My problem is I tried adding a guest list with an array

```
        vm.guests = [];

        vm.addGuest = function () {
            vm.guests.push(vm.newGuest);
        }

        vm.removeGuest = function (guest) {
            var index = vm.guests.indexOf(guest);
            vm.guests.splice(index, 1);
        }
```

html

```
  <input type="text" name="guests" id="guests" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.newGuest"  />
  <button type="submit" ng-click="vm.addGuest()" class="btn btn-primary">Add Guest</button>
    <div ng-repeat="guest in vm.guests track by $index">
     {{guest}}
```

I can add strings to the array from a single input/button

However, the array doesn't get passed to the event object.

```
{
  "eventType": "Birthday",
  "eventName": "Part at Lake Lettuce"
}
[
  "Joe",
  "Tom"
]
```

My goal is to add the array to the object

```
{
  "eventType": "Birthday",
  "eventName": "Part at Lake Lettuce"
  "guests":  [
     "Joe",
     "Tom"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Where on the event object are you trying to put the guests array?

Comment: just a heads up (you may not be doing this): if you're resetting your array anywhere, that will make you lose the data binding. for example, if you're trying to empty the array by using `vm.guests = []`. you should avoid this and use `vm.guests.length = 0` this will empty the array but maintain the data binding

Comment: @chic edited original post.

Comment: @AbdulAhmad I see what you're getting at,  I'm not _trying_ to empty the array but I can see how it could be emptying the array anyway. Biggest complication is my input ng-model gets passed to event, but the array doesn't because it's addGuest and goes to the function. Also `vm.guests.length = 0` errors saying `Cannot set property 'length' of undefined
    at new EventController `

Comment: Thanks, for the update. There's not enough of the controller for me to understand what's going on. I think I'm not following the events variable. Is it an array or object? And should `<td>{{events.eventType}} </td>` be `<td>{{vm.events.eventType}} </td>`?

Comment: @Chic  in event.view.html it is for `ng-model="vm.events.eventType"` but in my events.view.html it's `{{events.eventType}}` because I call localStorage using my EventService, and I've switched controllers. I didn't want to make the post too long so I guess I could link the repo https://github.com/teachtyler/Meet-Up-Event-Planner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `guests` property of your event. You may want to do this within the `event()` function.

```
    function event() {
        vm.dataLoading = true;
        vm.events.guests = vm.guests;
        EventService.Create(vm.events)
            .then(function (response) {
                if (response.success) {
                    FlashService.Success('Event created successful', true);
                    $location.path('/events');
                } else {
                    FlashService.Error(response.message);
                    vm.dataLoading = false;
                }
            });
    }
```

In that case you would have to initialize the guests array.

```
vm.guests = vm.events.guests || [];
```

Alternatively, you can have your guests modifier functions reference the event

```
    vm.addGuest = function () {
        vm.events.guests.push(vm.newGuest);
    }

    vm.removeGuest = function (guest) {
        var index = vm.events.guests.indexOf(guest);
        vm.events.guests.splice(index, 1);
    }
```

Also, I find the event vs events naming confusing. Within the EventController I'd suggest renaming your `vm.event()` function to `vm.createEvent()` and then calling the `events` model just `event`.